# Predict who will win between two teams based on their history

Tags: java, probability, prediction

So I have a project due on saturday (I started last week saturday). The project is a sports prediction program.

I spent all of yesterday researching and getting all the information on the EPL (English Premier League)  so I have all the results and fixtures in a database. As well as their current statistics (average goals per game, total wins, losses, league points, etc.)

I am currently comparing how many games they have won. What it does is retrieve data from the database from their 2 games over the season (they play 2 against every team, for those who don't watch soccer). It will either retrieve a "1" for a draw, or a name such as "Man Utd" for both games, or "Man Utd" and "Man City" for one game each.

How do I write the logic to predict which team is going to win on who won what? ie: Man Utd beat Man City and Man City beat Man utd, which is a 50-50 chance in the next game, but Man Utd beat Swansea twice, so Man Utd has a 90% chance of beating them in the next game.

Here is my code, which always comes out with a "50-50" so I dont know where I am going wrong.

This may be trivial, but not for me, please help as I am representing my school at a University where there will be scouts...

```
/**** get the result of the first game ****/
public String getGame1Result(String team1, String team2) throws SQLException{
    String resultOfGame = null;
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connection.conn_url, connection.conn_user, connection.conn_pass);
    statement = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT games_winner, games_draw FROM games WHERE games_team1 = '" + team2 + "' AND games_team2 = '" + team1 + "'");
    result = statement.executeQuery();
    while(result.next()){
        System.out.println(result.getString(1));
        System.out.println(result.getString(2));
        if(result.getString(1) == null){
            resultOfGame = result.getString(2);
        } else if(result.getString(2) == null) {
            resultOfGame = result.getString(1);
        } else {
            resultOfGame = "Did not work";
        }           
    }
    return resultOfGame;
}

/**** get the result of the second game ****/
public String getGame2Result(String team1, String team2) throws SQLException{
    String resultOfGame = null;
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connection.conn_url, connection.conn_user, connection.conn_pass);
    statement = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT games_winner, games_draw FROM games WHERE games_team1 = '" + team1 + "' AND games_team2 = '" + team2 + "'");
    result = statement.executeQuery();
    while(result.next()){
        System.out.println(result.getString(1));
        System.out.println(result.getString(2));
        if(result.getString(1) == null){
            resultOfGame = result.getString(2);
        } else if(result.getString(2) == null) {
            resultOfGame = result.getString(1);
        } else {
            resultOfGame = "Did not work";
        }   
    }
    return resultOfGame;
}

/**** compare the winner result ****/
private void compareGameWinnerResult(String game1Result, String game2Result,     String team1, String team2) {
    if((game1Result == "1") || (game2Result == "1")){   // checks for a draw
        System.out.println("draw");
        team1_winner_result = (float) 50;
        team2_winner_result = (float) 50;
    }
//      } else if((game1Result.equals(team1)) && (game2Result.equals(team1))) { // checks for a winner of both games
//          team1_winner_result = (float) 75;
//          team2_winner_result = (float) 25;
//      } 
        else if((game1Result.equals(team2)) &&     (game2Result.equals(team2))){    // checks for a winner of both games
        team1_winner_result = (float) 25;
        team2_winner_result = (float) 75;
    } else if((game1Result.equals(team1) && (game2Result == null))){    // checks for a winner and a draw
        team1_winner_result = (float) 75;
        team2_winner_result = (float) 25;
    } else if ((game1Result == null) && (game2Result.equals(team1))){   // checks for a winner and a draw
        team1_winner_result = (float) 25;
        team2_winner_result = (float) 75;
    } else if((game1Result.equals(team2) && (game2Result == null))){    // checks for a winner and a draw
        team1_winner_result = (float) 75;
        team2_winner_result = (float) 25;
    } else if ((game1Result == null) && (game2Result.equals(team2))){   // checks for a winner and a draw
        team1_winner_result = (float) 25;
        team2_winner_result = (float) 75;
    }else { // last resort
        team1_winner_result = (float) 50;
        team2_winner_result = (float) 50;
    }
    System.out.println(team1 + " " + team1_winner_result);
    System.out.println(team2 + " " + team2_winner_result);

}
```

Comment: Always use the `equals()` method for String value comparisons.

Comment: Also never use concatened queries. Use prepare statemens or you will expose your application to SQL injection.

Comment: Another tip : did you use traces/debugger in order to see which `if statement` ends up with `team*_winner_result = 50`?

Answer (score 1):

Change the below IF condition to use equals method,

```
if ((game1Result == "1") || (game2Result == "1"))
```

to

```
if ((game1Result.equals("1")) || (game2Result.equals("1")))
```

Comment: I know that, I tried it as well. What I am having an issue with is comparing the team names

Comment: Can you let us know what value is being passed in game1Result, game2Result, team1, team2 to `compareGameWinnerResult` method.

Comment: It is either the team name, null or 1